# Nothing to update "Doctrine"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine to try and update a table schema.  I was able to create the table.  I was also able to populate the table.  However after updating the comments in the Entity (I wanted some fields to become nullable), those changes did NOT get picked up.

I did create the entity with the "Annotations" option chosen.  But when I added this line "nullable=true" to the Entity on the field imageName nothing happens.  ie: when I run "./app/console doctrine:schema:update" I get the following output "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata."

Note, I have tried deleted the table via: ./app/console doctrine:database:drop --force and then recreating it via: ./app/console doctrine:database:create and then also ./app/console doctrine:schema:create but it STILL does not add my updated nullable field to imageName.

Comment: Did you originally execute doctrine:mapping:convert?  If so, you need to delete the generated xml/yml files before the schema:update command will use annotations.

Comment: @Cerad, where are these files found?  I looked under app/cache but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  I first of all created my entity "Foobar" using yml as the Configuration format.  I then wanted to use "annotation" as the configuration format so I manually deleted the Entity folder (I only had one table created), however I did NOT delete the configuration yml in the Resources/config/doctrine/Foobar.orm.yml.

Thus when I created the entity again, this time using the annotation as the configuration format, it was still linking to the yml configuration.  Removing that solved all the troubles.

I have however decided to stick to yml as I feel it is a little easier to read than the Doctrine Metadata found in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had been stuck with this for almost 2 days. Removing all the file in /src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the key was to clear Redis cache.

```
php app/console redis:flushdb
```

Answer (score 1):

I has this problem too. Have you right annotation before class declaration?

```
/**
* 
* @ORM\Entity <- this does the trick
*/
class MyEntityName
{
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check doctrine.yaml config file for orm mappings:

```
mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

As you see here all entities should have prefix (namespace) App\Entity
You have to check your entities namespace, it should be **App\Entity** or whatever you want in config